# Spring Boot Back-End with Angular Front-End getting status and metrics from prometheus and health endpoint but 401

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-boot-actuator

Running in to an issue with 401 error when deployed on cluster. Note the issue not occurring during local development. Issue occurs only once deployed on testing cluster. Currently the project is in only development/testing phase.

Back-End config(Spring properties file):

```html
server.port=8085
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
management.endpoint.health.show-details="ALWAYS"
management.server.port=${management.port:1234}
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, prometheus
```

Angular:
login is successful(using relative url's to port 8085 once deployed on the cluster) but after login my dashboard page makes calls to acutator health and prometheus end-points:

these are the URLs:
healthUrl: "http://localhost:1234/health"
metricsUrl: "http://localhost:1234/prometheus"

Spring Security:

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ActuatorWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class, InfoEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new ForwardedHeaderFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: A note on hitting the url's from the cluster using curl returns success:
healthUrl: "http://localhost:1234/health" metricsUrl: "http://localhost:1234/prometheus"
curl -u user_name http://localhost:1324/health succeeds from command line.

Comment: The 401 error is actually intermittent, the other error I may get is error connection refused. After stoping the back-end application restarting the error is now different. The login is still successful, but the calls to the metric and health url's are now returning:
GET http://localhost:1234/health net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
GET http://localhost:1234/prometheus net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
This is happening for both the pre-flight requests as well as the actual requests.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the entire class with the security configuration, including all annotations, so we can understand it better.

Comment: I have updated the original post which includes full spring security class. However note, that 401 error is intermittent, some times it is the 401 error and others it is the connection refused error. Local development with angular and spring boot back-end there is no such issue. Errors only occurring after deployment on test cluster.
Also note that my back-end controller is marked with annotation:
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")

Answer (score 0):

Below are couple of suggestions to dive deep into this

1. assuming your prometheus itself is being served over HTTPS, can you
   post your tls config? I am suspecting there is some issue with that,
   also can you recheck your spring-actuator config in prometheus file.
2. Can you check the metric, health, info path in prometheus file.

Comment: SSL is not being used. On the cluster. I am able to curl end points like so:
curl -u user_name http://localhost:1234/prometheus. It is only from the browser that I am having issue accessing these end-points.
Because of relative URL's, when I launch http://my_cluster_name:8085/ I am redirected to the login page http://my_cluster_name:8085/login. The login is successful and redirects me to my dashboard page where my angular components make calls to these end-points, this is when I am getting these intermittent errors.